# Finding minimum/maximum value in a Binary Indexed Tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees

I know how a BIT works. But I was wondering if a BIT can be used to find the minimum/maximum element in the complete range, or more specifically, to find the minimum (or maximum) value after all the update processes have been completed. Now, I know that this can very well be achieved using Segment Trees, but is it possible to do the same using a BIT?

I know the obvious way of traversing the complete BIT and calculating the value at each index. I am looking for a more efficient/optimized way.

Comment: Do you have a reference to a good description of Binary Indexed Trees?  (Not code, please: a description of the concept and algorithm.)  In particular, how are tree elements ordered?  And what do you mean by a "complete range" and "the update processes"?

Comment: Do you mean [tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)? (cc @D.W.)

Comment: Very interesting question. Theoretically in a balanced tree, the lowest value would be on left most node and the highest value in right most node?

Comment: If you do not know what a BIT is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree

Comment: @D.W. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.14.8917

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do better than $O(n)$.

Consider a set, where all values are $k$, except $2i$ and $2i-1$, which are $k-l$ and $k+l$ respectively. Any entry in the tree that contains a sum of $m$ values will be $mk$, with the single exception of the entry $2i-1$.

Thus, even if we knew we had a set of the form described, we had to look at $\frac n2$ entries in the worst case, in order to determine the minimum and maximum value.